# Is it possible to stop Apache jackrabbit garbage collector?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jackrabbit

We are using Apache jackrabbit v. 2.19.3 (not oak) and we are experiencing troubles with garbage collection. On our quite sizable repositorz, gc marking takes too long. The snippet looks like this:

```
...
final String nodesCount = session.getRepository().getDescriptor("jcr.repository.stats.nodes.count");
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.gc.GarbageCollector gc;

final org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCASessionHandle jcaSessionHandle = (org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCASessionHandle) session;
final org.apache.jackrabbit.core.XASessionImpl xaSession = (org.apache.jackrabbit.core.XASessionImpl) jcaSessionHandle.getManagedConnection().getSession(jcaSessionHandle);
gc = xaSession.createDataStoreGarbageCollector();
gc.setMarkEventListener(new DMSDataStoreGCListener(nodesCount));
gc.mark();
gc.stopScan();
gc.sweep();
...
```

Is this correct usage of the API? Is there a way to configure maximal possible time for garbage collection? Or split it so it does not run over whole repository... anything that would allow us to fit the garbage collection run within time window provided by our client to us.

Any help appreciated...